# WPF enabling multiple controls based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I need your help. In WPF and MVVM, I want to enable multiple controls based on multiple checkboxes. I have two grids (A and B) and two checkboxes (X and Y).

if X is checked and Y is unchecked -> A is enabled, B is disabled

if X is unchecked and Y is checked -> B is enabled, A is disabled

if X is unchecked and Y is unchecked -> A and B are disabled

if X is checked and Y is checked -> this situation is forbidden

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are mvvm, the viewmodel get updates from the checkbox; you calculate the state of the grid in a variable and update the grid status ( XisChecked ==> calculate AGridIsEnabled )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do this in `XAML` only:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="X" Content="X"/>
        <Grid Background="Red" Name="A" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=X}">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox Name="Y" Content="Y"/>
        <Grid Background="Blue" Name="B" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Y}">
            <TextBlock/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```